# What does "$\;\cdot :\;$" mean? As in "$\;\cdot : \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{V}\to\mathbb{V}\;$"

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

In the context of the discussion here, it seems like the dot followed by colon in Fig. 2.21 means "given..." but can anybody point me to a page where this (these?) symbol is defined as such?

Is this a symbolic logic symbol or from some other branch of math?

Comment: It is simply a function declaration, like $f:\mathbb C\times\mathbb V\to\mathbb V$, except that the function is named $\cdot$ instead of $f$.

Comment: $f:A\to B$ means a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$. In your case the function is called $\cdot$ (because multiplication is usually wrriten as $x\cdot y$).

Comment: But it's implicitly applied in "infix" form. Properly speaking, with only that as a description of $\cdot$, you should write $$ \cdot(z, \mathbf v)$$ rather than $z \cdot \mathbf v$. Far better (I think) would be to write, "We have a 'scalar mutliplication' function $m : \Bbb C \times \Bbb V \to \Bbb V$, but we usually write $z \cdot \mathbf v$ for $m(z, \mathbf v)$ to mimic the notion of multiplication in ordinary algebra."

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Post your comment as an answer, along with the observation that this "multiplication" is multiplying a vector by a complex scalar.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $A, B$ are sets, then a function $f$ that takes elements of $A$ as input and produces elements of $B$ as output is written as $f: A \to B$. In this case, the set $A$ is $\mathbb C \times \mathbb V$, and the set $B$ is $\mathbb V$. The "name of the function" is the dot $\cdot$. If you took this very literally, that means that you would write $\cdot(c, v)$ for $c \in \mathbb C, v \in \mathbb V$, but from context or experience you would understand that you use an infix notation from $\cdot$, so you actually write $c \cdot v$ instead.